# Adding two integer JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add two numbers in JavaScript, but the result is inexact. This my example:

```
var x = 11.12, y = 11.07;



console.log(x + y);  // the result is 22.189999999999998 but the real result is 22.19
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: you can read [this great article](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/javascripts-number-type-8d59199db1b6#.htmwy5ugp) that explains why that happens

Comment: you can try `console.log((x + y).toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```js
var x = 11.12, y = 11.07;
var result = (parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y)).toFixed(2);
console.log( result );
```